# How does the second form of c++ std::make_any work?

Tags: c++, c++17

There are two form of the c++ function `std::make_any`,

```
template< class T, class... Args >
std::any make_any( Args&&... args );                                (1)

template< class T, class U, class... Args >
std::any make_any( std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args );   (2)
```

How does the second form work?  Why it is not just

```
template< class T, class U>
std::any make_any( std::initializer_list<U> il) ?
```

For example, in this statement,

```
std::any a = std::make_any<std::list<int>>({1,2,3}).
```

Or can you call it with both an initializer_list and together with some other arguments, such as, {1,2,3}, 4,5? Is the args here for constructing il, or for list?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this second for exists is due to `std::initializer_list` not playing well with template argument deduction. Imagine you own implementation (using `std::make_any` as an implementation) that does *not* offer the second form;

```
template< class T, class... Args >
std::any poor_make_any(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_any<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This works well for e.g.

```
struct Test {
    Test(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
    Test(int) {}
};

std::any x = poor_make_any<Test>(42);
```

but it fails to compile for

```
std::any x = poor_make_any<Test>({1, 2, 3});
```

again because `std::initializer_list<int>` cannot be deduced by the compiler. While you can always specify the second template argument, this is overly verbose for a function from the `make_` family that is meant to be a deduction helper.

And finally, the remaining arguments are just additional flexibility that you get for free. Imagine this additional constructor for the `Test` example,

```
Test(std::initializer_list<int>, int) {}
```

It just works with

```
std::any x = std::make_any<Test>({1,2,3}, 42);
```

While if that variadic second part wasn't there, you had to

```
std::any x = std::make_any<Test, std::initializer_list<int>, int>({1,2,3}, 42);
```

which is obviously not super convenient.

Comment: You made it very clear, thanks!  Now I understood it that, here, "std::initializer_list<U> il" is just for the first parameter for constructor of 'T'; and args could have zero or more to follow.

Comment: It's by the way a good question IMHO. Not sure where the downvote came from, maybe the missing formatting in the first version.